# PIMPL idiom and copy semantic

Tags: c++, deep-copy, pimpl-idiom

I'm using a library which contains a lot of classes builded using the **PIMPL** idiom. What I found bad, in my opinion, is that those classes are implemented using a `std::shared_ptr` to the implementation. This means the objects are actually "implicitly shared". My question is: is this the correct way to implement PIMPL? Or PIMPL and "implicitly shared" are two different idioms and therefore should not be mixed by default? Which is the correct way to handle the copy semantic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMO, the correct way to implement pimpl is to use `std::unique_ptr`. 
It's more efficient and the pimpl object should be uniquely owned by the visible class, not be shared (and you don't have to bother with copy semantic).

PIMPL and "implicitly shared" are two different idioms indeed.

If you still have to use `std::shared_ptr` for pimpl then you will have to explicitly define copy assignement operations (because the compiler won't be able to generate the correct ones).

Comment: I agree, I find the 'std::unique_ptr' way better than the 'std::shared_ptr' implementation. But sometimes when you are writing a library, you need to hide the implementation of small copyable objects too, i.e. lib::Point3d or lib::UnicodeString. My idea is that no standard smart pointer can do the correct job, if I've understoop correctly what the PIMPL idiom has been created for.

Answer (score 2):

As coincoin said, use a unique_ptr instead of a shared_ptr. If you want to make your class copyable, you can always call the copy constructor of your pimpl object in the copy constructor of your visible class.

```
class A {
    class impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> pimpl;
public:
    A(int x);
    A(A const& old);
    ...
};
```

Implementation:

```
class A::impl {
    int x;
public:
    impl(int x)
        : x(x)  {}
    impl(impl const& old)
        : x(old.x) {}
};

A::A(int x)
    : pimpl(std::make_unique<impl>(x)) {}

A::A(A const& old)
    : pimpl(std::make_unique<impl>(*old.pimpl)) {}
```

Comment: Not bad, but for every class you'll have to define the copy constructor and copy assignment operator (probably also the move ones?). If we agree that PIMPL should not interfere with the copy semantic of the class (which is actually what the question is about), I'd suggest that a specific smart pointer is the best solution.

Comment: If you are having enough pimpl'ed classes, that might be a viable option. Making a smart pointer class that behaves well in all circumstances (especially with exceptions) does require a bit of thought though. If there are only a few pimpl'ed classes, just going with unique_ptr (and probably copy constructor defined as = default) might be the simpler solution.

Comment: std::unique_ptr has deleted copy constructor and operator, so I guess it won't allow a =default definition in the owning class. Once you use a std::unique_ptr for a member, the whole class becomes uncopiable, that is the huge limitation of this approach. But, again, it still looks more safe than the std::shared_ptr approach.

Comment: Oh, I meant copy defaulted constructer on the pimpl class. In my example I implemented it manually, but I wanted to make clear that a lot of work can be saved there.